# Blank page if I declare(strict_types=1); in PHP 7 at top of the file

Tags: php, strict, php-7

Recently I was checking out on PHP 7, specifically [return type declaration](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types) and [type hinting](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5). I have compiled PHP 7 from source(master branch from [Github](https://github.com/php/php-src)) and running it in Ubuntu 14.04 virtual box. I tried to run following code to get a test of new [Exceptions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7). But it Gave a blank page.

```
<?php

function test(): string {

    return [];
}

echo test();
```

Then I realize I have to set error to be displayed on screen. So I added old fashioned `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` like below,

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function test(): string {

    return [];
}

echo test();
```

that gave me following `TypeError` as expected according to this [Throwable interface](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throwable-interface) RFC

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of test() must be of the
>   type string, array returned in /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php on line
>   7 in /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php(10): test() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php on line 7

Digging further I added `declare(strict_types=1);` at the top as below,

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function test(): string {

    return [];
}

echo test();
```

and bang, error just got disappeared leaving me with blank page. I cant figure out why it is giving me a blank page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After searching around the google and RFC's I came to follwing sentence in [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5),

> This RFC further proposes the addition of a new optional per-file
>   directive, declare(strict_types=1);, which makes all function calls
>   and return statements within a file have “strict” type-checking for
>   scalar type declarations, including for extension and built-in PHP
>   functions.

This means there was nothing wrong with directive `declare(strict_types=1)` but the problem was the way I was calling `ini_set()` function. It expects second parameter to be of `string` type.

```
string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )
```

I was passing `int` instead, and hence the setting needed to display errors itself failed to set and hence I was hit
with a blank page by PHP strict mode. I then changed the code a bit and passed the string `"1"` as below and it worked.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

ini_set('display_errors', "1");

function test(): string {

    return [];
}

echo test();
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer it, I would probably have come across the same thing when I finally start playing with 7

Comment: Was very helpful for me. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

as the error states your function expect you to return string but instead you return an array! And function complains which is normal. So on your return simply put some string value. That's it!