# PHP strict types - weird boolean behavior

Tags: php

i have this code:

```
<?php

    declare(strict_types=1);

    # test_1 with bool
    function test_1(bool $bool) {
        return $bool ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }

    # test_2 with boolean
    function test_2(boolean $bool) {
        return $bool ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }

    $value = false;

    # Why does this work ...
    echo test_1($value) . "<br>";

    # ... but this doesn't?
    echo test_2($value) . "<br>";


?>
```

Strict types seem to work with bool but not with boolean.

php.net [says](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types):

> Aliases for the above scalar types are not supported. Instead, they are treated as class or interface names. For example, using boolean as a parameter or return type will require an argument or return value that is an instanceof the class or interface boolean, rather than of type bool

But somehow i don't get it. Can anyone explain that to me please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501219/blank-page-if-i-declarestrict-types-1-in-php-7-at-top-of-the-file .... Read This

Comment: I already did, but this is a completely different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP supports only `int`, `float`, `bool`, `string` and `array` types. Any of different return *type* (like `boolean`) references to class name.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1)

class boolean {}

func testReturnBoolean(): boolean {
    // this function should return instance of
    // class "boolean", not bool type (true/false)
}

func testReturnBool(): bool {
    // this function should return true or false,
    // otherwise it throws an exception
}

func testReturnBoolOrNull():? bool {
    // this function should return true, false or null
    // otherwise it throws an exception
    // syntax :? string works since php 7.1
}
```

More about [function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) and [return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration).

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't allow you to use *boolean* for the type definition, because the keyword is *bool*. If you type *boolean*, it will interprete it as a call to a class name. What is hard to understand?

Comment: It seems like op answered his own question without knowing it

Comment: Yeah, but i found it a bit confusing because `<?php echo (boolean)"123" . (bool)"123"; ?>` works. But i got your point.